# Problem visualizing a specific column in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, data-analysis

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pi6At.png)

I don't understand why the Gender column is duplicated. I've gone through the lines of code and can't find a solution.

Here are the lines of code:

```
df['Gender'].value_counts()
df['Gender'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100
frequency = df['Gender'].value_counts()
percentage = df['Gender'].value_counts(normalize=True) * 100

dist_qualitative_frequency = pd.DataFrame({'Frequency': frequency, 'Percentage (%)': percentage})

dist_qualitative_frequency = pd.DataFrame({'Frequency': frequency, 'Percentage (%)': percentage})

dist_qualitative_frequency.rename(index={0: 'Male', 1: 'Female'}, inplace=True)

dist_qualitative_frequency.rename_axis('Gender', axis='columns', inplace=True)

dist_qualitative_frequency
```

Resolve the Genre column that appears duplicated.

Comment: "I don't understand why the Gender column is duplicated." - What exactly does this mean? Exactly how do you think the output should be different, and why? I only see one "Male" entry and one "Female" entry in the column, so that seems to be as it should be.

Comment: Do `print(dist_qualitative_frequency.columns)` and see if `name='Gender'`, which would indicate that it is not a column name but the index name because of `rename_axis`